# Data Science Companies

Tags: bigdata, algorithms

I'm interested in data science market. I was expecting that there would be a lot of companies who are making algorithms and models for companies like in kaggle competitions. But i struggle to find any. Practically every data science company is selling some automated software which makes algorithms/models by its own. So why is that so? Did i understand situation correctly? and if there are companies who make algorithms and models which are the leaders and best companies in that field. thanks p.s. sorry for my bad english

Comment: What do you mean by a `data science companies`?  My company delivers food, but we do some pretty serious DS stuff here :)

Comment: This kind of work is often done by external consultancy companies (at least here in EU), but they tend to offer whole package of services, therefore you don't find often pure Data Science companies (but they exist). So i'd say look for those and ask how much Data Science they do.

Comment: It would help to know what country you are from and what your background is.

Answer (score 2):

Some of the biggest companies in the world are 'data science' companies; facebook, for instance, performs targeted advertising based on analyzing users preference.  In essence, it's the most highly trained recommendation engine ever, as it knows a great deal about it's consumers.  At it's heart, Google is an advertisement firm, and similarly leverages user information to provide targeted messaging to consumers.  The same can be said for Amazon, Twitter, and most likely pokemon go.

If you're thinking of a more purely 'data science as a service' company, larger consultancy firms such as the Boston Consulting Group have always incorporated analytics in their services, and have certainly profited from the proliferation of data.  They don't say "we do data science", because people care more about getting the right answer, than how the answer is obtained.

As far as Kaggle goes, while it's an awesome resource, and it provides cool tutorials and data sets, if you're a professional data scientist, then you don't work for free ;-)  If a billion dollar company can harvest even a 1% gain in efficiency by offering a $50K prize, they can recoup that money very quickly.  If you're only asset is intellectual property, you need to be cautious about giving it away.

Answer (score 0):

In the market there is two types of companies operating in data sciences algorithm :
The First ones companies how's operating in the different sector and hiring data scientists to analyse or predict their business.
The second kind: is software provider how's customizing software for their clients for the specific business and you can find them by fields like Data analysis for pharmaceutical products, Statistical Forecast pharmaceutical products.